# How to add dynamically an input file tag with image javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

I want to add input file dynamically with an image from another input either js or jquery

I have two input type fields

```
<input type="file" name="f1" />


<input type="file" name="f2[]" />
```

When we upload a multiple files in `f2[]` I need some specific file in `f1` file control

can anyone help me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If we select a file in `f2` need to add in `f1` aswell

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking

Comment: If user selects a file from browser from `name=f2[]` input field, I want that file in `name=f1` input field by using javascript/jquery.

Comment: And you want `f2[]` to contain multiple values?

Answer (score 0):

First off:

`<input type="file" name="f2[]" />`

Will not hold multiple files like you said, you need:

`<input type="file" name="f2[]" multiple />`

Secondly, you cannot set the value of a `input type='file'`, this is for security reasons; otherwise people could create a script that uploads files from your computer without your knowledge.

e.g.

```
<form name="foo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" value="c:/passwords.txt">
</form>
<script>document.foo.submit();</script>
```

*Credits to BalusC, and his post in '[How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)'*